# Using GCP Connection objects in Google Cloud Composer Airflow DAG python operator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, connection, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a series of python scripts that draw data from Google Sheets using the gspread library authorized using a json service account keyfile through the oauth2client library:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(gcp_config_yaml_path,scopes)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
cur = config['tables_to_load'][i]

sheet = client.open_by_url(cur['spreadsheet_url']).worksheet(cur['sheet_name'])
df=pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())
```

I need to convert this into an Airflow DAG using Google Cloud Composer and I would like to take advantage of the connections functionality of Airflow (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_a_connection_to_another_project).

I've uploaded the json keyfile object and created the connection object in the Airflow UI (per. option 'i' in step 'd - iv' in '#2 create a new connection') and I'm able to reference that object in my code using:

```
client = BaseHook.get_connection('google_cloud_default')
```

But that's about as far as I can get. Each time I try to call an argument in the connection, I get an error that the argument doesn't exist (keyfile_json, keyfile_dict, scopes, keyfile_path, client, spreadsheets, etc.) and I can't seem to find any documentation on what attributes should be available in the object: (https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/gcp/hooks/base/index.html#airflow.gcp.hooks.base.CloudBaseHook).

**Any insight on methods for authorizing a Google Sheets connection in a GCP Cloud Composer Airflow environment would be a HUGE help!**

Thanks so much in advance!